# ios EXC_BAD_ACCESS on an implementation

Tags: ios, implementation, exc-bad-access

```
@implementation ContentView // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line
```

log of `self` from the breakpoint:

```
<ContentView: 0x96a4690; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = (null)>
```

What's going on here? Is my object gone?

Comment: That line is not executable, so I don't know how you got there but try to find out where the error is REALLY coming from.  Could be that you didn't return self from the init method...or overrode a UIKit method but forgot to call super.  Post more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this to explain EXC_BAD_ACCESS

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

Basically, it happens because you are using memory that is not mapped to your process. This usually happens because you are accessing released objects or the heap is corrupt.  The line of code you show is not executable -- it doesn't result in the "memory use" that could trigger this error.

To help debug it:

1. Run an Analyze and fix everything it flags
2. Turn on Zombies and see if it complains that you are sending a message to a released object.

Comment: #1 was good (i'm pretty strict about that) and #2 I turned on zombies and the problem went away, but I never got any log messages about the problem. What gives? As soon as I turn zombies off, the problem comes back..

Comment: When you turn on Zombies, objects will no longer be dealloced when their retainCount hits 0.  Instead, if you send a message to an object with retainCount 0, it should log to the Console.  Are you sure you are looking at the console?

Comment: I watched in the only console I know of, where all of the `NSLog` information goes. (shift + cmd + C)

Comment: This is extremely odd.  Try to force a message with something like this `NSNumber n = [[NSNumber alloc] init]; [n release]; [n release];`  That should complain into the console on the second release.

Comment: ah, I should note than this project uses ARC so I can't force a release :(

Comment: It's tricky to cause a need for zombies under ARC.  You could do it with a weak or assign property.  Under ARC EXC_BAD_ACCESS is harder (not impossible) to have happen.  Is there anything odd about your project (third-party libs), do you use any C memory management (malloc/free).  Do you have any unchecked casts?

Comment: I fixed this by revamping the code. Instead of using ObjC blocks I went a parameterized route so I'm sure something just wasn't retained right. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! #1 actually did it - I went on to fix the warnings as well! saved me after 2 days of work!